# Derived class can't see parent class properly

Tags: c++

I'm seeing two problems in a setup like this:

```
namespace ns1
    {
     class ParentClass
     {
      protected:
       void callback();
     };
    }

    namespace ns1
    {
     namespace ns2
     {
      class ChildClass : public ParentClass
      {
        public:
        void method()
        {
         registerCallback(&ParentClass::callback);
        }
      };
     }
    }
```

1. ChildClass::method() gives a compile error: "*'ns1::ParentClass::callback' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'ns1::ParentClass'*"
2. `ParentClass *pObj = new ChildClass()` gives an error, that it can't do the conversion without a cast. C++ can down-cast happily, no?

Comment: Can you post the full context in which `2.` gives an error?

Comment: ParentClass *pObj = new ChildClass() is compiling fine using your example (commenting out the illegal registerCallback call) in VC10B2. You'll need to post more details about your error.

Comment: Why is registerCallback illegal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
registerCallback(&ParentClass::callback);
```

...to:

```
registerCallback(&ChildClass::callback);
```

The reason is because &ParentClass::callback is a fully-qualified typename, not resolved from the context of ChildClass but from global context.  In other words, it is the same problem as this:

```
class Thingy
{
protected:
    virtual int Foo() {};
};


int main() 
{
    Thingy t;
    t.Foo();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: That's interesting; you can call ParentClass::callback() from inside method() just fine, but taking a pointer to it results in an error. Why is that?

Comment: Edited with a hopefully helpful explanation.

Answer (score 3):

A derived class can only access protected members of a base class if that base class instance is - and is accessed via - a derived class instance. A derived class doesn't have access to protected members of other types of base class.

**Edit:** When forming a pointer to a member, a protected member of a base class may be used but the name used to scope the member name must be a derived class name and not the base class name so this 'cannot access' error is correct.

For point 2., with `using ns1::ParentClass;` and a `using ns1::ns2::ChildClass;` at the outer scope after the complete declaration of `ChildClass`, I don't get any error with your statement.

Comment: It is being accessed via a derived class instance.

Comment: No it's not, there is no instance when creating a pointer to member with `&scope::member_name`.

Comment: But edited to add the _real_ reason that the generated error is correct. You are allowed to access protected members of base class when forming a pointer to member even though there is no instance involved in this operation.

Answer (score -1):

Declare function as public.

Make sure that base class has virtual destructor..